# What is Timeline.dart used for in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I reading the code of flutter. I find some code in framework.dart like

`Timeline.startSync('Build', arguments: timelineWhitelistArguments);`

`Timeline.finishSync();`

I found the document in this website

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-developer/Timeline-class.html

But I still don't understand what is the purpose of this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used to check the app performance on a timeline in Flutter DevTools.

You can read more about it here: [Tracing Any Dart Code Performance](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#tracing-any-dart-code-performance)

**EDITED**
Also found a good article about profiling Flutter apps using timelines at medium.
[Medium Article](https://medium.com/flutter/profiling-flutter-applications-using-the-timeline-a1a434964af3)